# Where can I find fixed cost Node.js hosting?

Tags: node.js, web-hosting

I need to host my node.js web application in non cloud hosting. I mean fixed resources and fixed monthly/yearly cost not per usage like many hosts of php and java. Is there this kind of host?

Comment: Every VPS instance from every hoster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you're looking for, but you can pay for non-dedicated Node app hosting on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). Heroku pricing is based on how many dynos you decide to throw at your app, along with the cost of premium databases, support, and plugins. They charge by how fancy the resources are that you want to use, not by the number of requests/bandwidth/usage/etc.

In my opinion, while it is relatively pricey in some cases, Heroku is an excellent Node app host (and there's a free tier you can play around with).

Comment: free tier is not available anymore :-(

Comment: There are plenty of newer alternatives now, including Railway and Vercel (with a free tier).